# Programmtically updating modified date value of a file

Tags: 2010, migration, document

I am trying to migrate some document into SharePoint 2010 doc library and would like to retain the "modified" and "modified by" value of the document. I am able to store the document into a doc lib and set the "modified by" value but cannot store the "modified" date properly. Following is my code:

```
            var list = web.Lists[new Guid("751e4d84-44a8-4d58-8151-2f14fca70645")];
            var folderItem = list.RootFolder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Tax");
            foreach (File x in files) {
                var author = context.Web.EnsureUser(x.LastModifiedBy);
                var lastModified = x.LastModified;
                SPFile uploadedFile = folderItem.Files.Add(x.FileName, x.Content, author, author, lastModified,
                                                           lastModified);
                uploadedFile.Item["Created"] = lastModified;
                uploadedFile.Item["Modified"] = lastModified;
                uploadedFile.Item.SystemUpdate(false);
            }
```

As you can see I have 4 files in the files collection. For some weird reason, the first file is not retaining the modified date I am setting. The last 3 files store the date just fine. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: As far as I can see nothing is wrong here. Did you tried to set `lastModified` to some different DateTime value (eg. Now) - just to check if all files are updated as expected? Maybe is problem in first file Modified date field but I am not sure what could be wrong with it.

Comment: And try code example provided at [SPFileCollection.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439259.aspx) without using LINQ. I really don't have a clue what is wrong. I am just trying to give you some troubleshooting ideas. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue... I have changed the code from:

```
uploadedFile.Item.SystemUpdate(false);
```

to:

```
uploadedFile.Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

And that did the trick!

Comment: Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms481195.aspx

When passing false into the SystemUpdate method, you are saying do NOT update the current version, timestamp, etc. If you set it to true, you will have a new version and modified date. However, your solution will retain the current version (if necessary) but update the timestamp