# Change 'Created' column/field value

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, custom-control

I have a business requirement of changing the date of 'created' column/field of selected document/s in a document library(it has to be changed to current system date). This has to be done by adding a custom button to the ribbon and providing authorization to the button.
Please let me know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be possible. See [this article](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2009/10/10/changing-system-properties-for-an-item-from-the-sharepoint-user-interface-part-1/) as reference, and sample code [here](http://spfields.codeplex.com/). In that sample a custom field was developed to achieve the same goal, but you can easily translate that into a ribbon component (button) as well.

```
yourFile.Item["Created"] = DateTime.Now;
yourFile.Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

The sample allows only site admins (`Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin`) to use the field.

See this [related thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19914/programmtically-updating-modified-date-value-of-a-file) too.